Why is a PowerShell function working differently depending on whether it's imported from a file or a PS Module?
I have the following PowerShell function. I have excluded the parts of the function that are not relevant.
Function Add-TradeDetailElementBlocks
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$False, Mandatory=$True)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$Path,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$False, Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$DateFormat,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$False, Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$TradeImportXPath,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$False, Mandatory=$True)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [System.Data.DataRow[]]$BlockList,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$False, Mandatory=$True)]
        [int]$DealId
    )

    $Xml = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlDocument
    $File = Get-childItem -Path $Path
    $Xml.Load($File)

    $TradeImportNode = $Xml.SelectSingleNode($TradeImportXPath)

    $PriceMultiplier,$AmountMultiplier = Get-Multiplier $DealId

    foreach($Block in $BlockList)
    {
        
        $TradeDetailsElement = $Xml.CreateElement('tradeDetail')
        $TradeImportNode.AppendChild($TradeDetailsElement) | Out-Null

        $DatesElement = $Xml.CreateElement('dates')
        $TradeDetailsElement.AppendChild($DatesElement) | Out-Null
        $TradeDetailsElement.dates = Convert-DateToString -Date $Block.dates -Format $DateFormat

        $Block.price = ([double]$Block.price * $PriceMultiplier).ToString("N10")
        $Block.amount = ([double]$Block.amount * $AmountMultiplier).ToString("N6")


        if($Block.times -ne $Null)
        {
            $TimesElement = $Xml.CreateElement('times')
            $TradeDetailsElement.AppendChild($TimesElement) | Out-Null
            $TradeDetailsElement.times = [string]($Block.times)
        }

        :
        :
        
        $Xml.Save($Path)
    }
}

This function reads values from a data row object (i.e. $Block) and writes the values into an XML file. The structure of the XML file isn't relevant in this case.
If I store this function in a Powershell file and import the file into my script using dot notation, I get a failure at the line if($Block.times -ne $Null) because the times property does not exist in the data row. This can be expected behaviour.
However, if the function is contained within a module that is imported into the script using Import-Module, the same code will work without a problem (even though the times element does not exist in the data row).
What is causing this differing behaviour?

Please post the error message in full

Are you using strict mode? It's unclear what you mean by getting a failure if times doesnt exist.

You do realize that with $File = Get-childItem -Path $Path the $File variable can very well be an array of FileInfo and DirectoryInfo objects? Then to load a single file it is best to use the .FullName property of that one file: $Xml.Load($File.FullName)

Per @SantiagoSquarzon, your dot-sourced script is being executed in the same scope as the main script - it’s likely “Strict Mode” is already enabled somewhere earlier in your script. By contrast, modules run in their own scope with their own Strict Mode settings - try this for an example:  Set-StrictMode -Version “Latest”; $x = @{ "aaa" = "bbb" }; $y = $x.ccc and you’ll get your original error. If, in the same session you then run $myModule = new-module { function aaa { $x = @{ "aaa" = "bbb" }; $y = $x.ccc } }; aaa you’ll get no error…

You are correct @mclayton that the strict mode has been set earlier in the script. I assumed the setting of strict mode would also apply to the module. But if I understand you correctly, you are saying that this was a wrong assumption and the strict mode will not be set by default in the module?

Thanks for flagging @Theo. I do realise that but in this case, it doesn't matter because there will only ever be one file in the path. However, maybe it's worth updating the code, just in case.
